# Tags in graphite using micrometer are not send

Tags: kotlin, grafana, graphite, micrometer

Using **graphite 1.1.5** and grafana, I have tried to show the timer for each value of the tag. I am using **micrometer 1.3.1**. The problem is that the whole name I am using exists, but without tags.
The response in grafana from graphite:

```
    {
      target: "xxx.tasks.duration.p99",
      datapoints: Array...,
      tags: {
        name: "xxx.tasks.duration.p99"
      },
      title: "xxx.tasks.duration.p99"
    }
```

The code in my kotlin app:

```
Timer.builder("xxx.tasks.duration1")
    .tag("type", taskType)
    .register(metricsRegistry)
    .record(toMeasureLambda)
```

So it looks that my tag "type" is ignored. Do you have any sugesstions? How can I show the execution time of each task with type?

Comment: what are the expected values of the tag "type"?

Comment: also, your timer in code is named "xxx.tasks.duration1" but the metric in graphite is named "xxx.tasks.duration". Is this a typo in the question? Are you looking at the wrong metric in graphite?

Comment: Can you post your configuration files? Which protocol are you using? Are you sure that the NamingConvention you configured is the one you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can debug `GraphiteReporter` and check which `GraphiteSender` is been used. After, check what is sending `GraphiteSender`. 90% the problem is there.

If you are using Statsd, the question is a bit different.
You can redirect the the line sink to System.out so you can check what is coming from your application.